# Richfaces 3.3.3 Issue with IE9

Tags: richfaces, internet-explorer-9

My application is currently running with JSF 1.2 and rich faces 3.3.3 Final.
I'm having issues with rendering rich faces skin over Internet Explorer 9 Final version. It doesn't load rich faces skin, and from network tab i can view that this file is received as 'text/html' rather than 'text/css' with a get status  of 500. 
I got this information from the following link,
[IE9 + RichFaces Rendering problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978407/ie9-richfaces-rendering-problem)

A possible solution to it is to move to RF4 but for it we have to move to JSF 2.0 and thats very time consuming process and very expensive too.

I have tried the solution specified in thread http://community.jboss.org/thread/156720
by Kenneth Christensen as well, but still it didnt help me ;-(

Can any one please suggest a more suited solution for it :-)

Thanks,
Ubaid

Comment: Are you sure the browser is definitely switching to IE-8 mode, did you put the meta tag directly after the opening head tag?, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode2 where it mentions that the The X-UA-Compatible header "must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements.

Answer (score 2):

Patch to solve the problem RichFaces 3.3.3.Final xIE9

http://ruleoftech.com/2013/patching-richfaces-3-3-3-ajax-js-for-ie9

Comment: This is the best answer - fixing the library with the issue (Sarissa).
All the other solutions cause later IE versions to emulate IE8 - losing features added in the newer browsers (CSS3 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

put this in your page:

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

for me "IE=EmulateIE8" did not work. Neither in meta tag nor in filter. I changed it to "IE=8" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A change was made to CSS handling in IE6, IE7, and IE8 to block all cross-origin stylesheets unless they have been delivered with the proper HTTP response header:

```
Content-Type: text/css
```

http://technology-for-human.blogspot.ca/2011/12/jsf-12-myfaces-richfaces-33x-ie-9.html