# A4J reRender not working on IE9 [Working on IE8]

Tags: internet-explorer, web, richfaces, ajax4jsf, rerender

The idea is to cascade the values from the `store combobox` based on the selected value on the `customer combobox`. Here's a code snippet:

Customer Combobox:

```
<rich:comboBox directInputSuggestions="true" width="220"
      listStyle="text-align:left;" enableManualInput="false"
      id="customerList" value="#{gpsReport.selectedCustomer}" >

      <a4j:support actionListener="#{gpsReport.selectCustomer}"
            event="onchange" reRender="storeList"
            ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true" />

      <f:selectItems value="#{gpsReport.customers}" />

</rich:comboBox>
```

Store Combobox:

```
<rich:comboBox directInputSuggestions="true" width="220"
      listStyle="text-align:left;" enableManualInput="false"
      id="storeList" value="#{gpsReport.selectedStore}">

      <a4j:support actionListener="#{gpsReport.selectStore}"
             event="onchange"
             ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true" />

      <f:selectItems value="#{gpsReport.stores}" />

</rich:comboBox>
```

This is actually working on IE8. However, on IE9, changing the value of Customer Combobox removes the Stores Combobox. I wonder what's happening.

Thanks SO!

Comment: For the meantime, I'll let the users turn their compatibility mode on if any of them uses IE. But I think no would dare to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichFaces 3.x does not support IE9. Refer to this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326359/854386

Comment: Your answer from the other topic was very straight forward. So reRender was not the culprit. Thank you Andrey!