# Ajax request issue in IE9 using Richfaces 3.3.3 Final

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces 3.3.3 Final and JSF 2.0, some times any of the ajax request occurs a script error will appear like

" SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.

3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript, line 143 character 96 "

It appears only in IE 9. After refreshing the page it works fine.

Comment: +1 I'm also seeing these issues like ajax stuff not working in IE. After trying to debug my own app, I just tried showcase & to my surprise even their showcase isn't working correctly for ajax stuff on IE 10! (not using compatibility mode in IE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tempororily i resolve the problem by replacing the below lines. It works fine.

Find the file AJAX.js in richfaces-impl.jar

Location :  /org/ajax4jsf/javascript/scripts/AJAX.js

line number 1398

```
      oldnode.outerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newnode);
```

and replace it by

```
  if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined") 
   {
      oldnode.outerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newnode);
   } 
   else if (typeof xmlNode.xml != "undefined") 
   {
      oldnode.outerHTML = xmlNode.xml;
   }
```

line number 1627

```
        dst.setAttribute(attr,value);
```

and replace by adding try, catch

```
try 
{
        dst.setAttribute(attr, value);
    }
catch (err) 
{
        //alert('Error');
    }
```

(or)

make a copy of AJAX.js file and modified the above lines and include this file into your main page that will replace the old one.

Answer (score 2):

RichFaces 3.x does not support IE9. Refer to this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326359/854386