# Is JSF1.2 compatibile for all the browsers?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am working on a project which is developed in JSF1.2 and RichFaces3.0.1. But application is not supporting all the browsers even mozilla and chrome i need to make it compatible for all the major browsers.

Can you confirm me that JSF1.2 and RichFaces3.0.1 components will compatible for all the browsers.

Thanks
RK Thota

Comment: You really should update, RF 3.0.1 was released in 2007, Chrome was released a year after that.

Comment: Please look into primefaces, it has more controls and modern browser support.

Comment: HI Noman but my project in RichFaces 3.0 can i use Primefaces even ?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.3 are compatible with Firefox, Chrome, Sarafi, Opera, IE (8+). Try update your library to latest RichFaces 3 version (3.3.4).

Comment: RichFaces 3 does not support IE9 out of the box (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978407/ie9-richfaces-rendering-problem/7326359#7326359).

Comment: @Andrey after emulate IE8 in compatibility mode application works good in IE9, IE10.