# Ajax scripts don't work in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I am using JSF 1,2 and I found that IE9 or higher doesn't support  Ajax scripts and requests. In my project I have the same problems and errors as u can reproduce on: [this source](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/actionparam.jsf?c=actionparam&tab=usage) using IE 9+

```
<ui:composition
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:form>
    <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
        <a4j:commandButton value="Set Name to Alex"  reRender="rep" >
            <a4j:actionparam name="username" value="Alex" assignTo="#{userBean.name}"/>
        </a4j:commandButton>
        <rich:spacer width="20" />
        <a4j:commandButton value="Set Name to John"  reRender="rep" >
            <a4j:actionparam name="username" value="John" assignTo="#{userBean.name}"/>
        </a4j:commandButton>
    </rich:panel>
    <rich:spacer height="1" />
    <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
        <h:outputText id="rep" value="Selected Name:#{userBean.name}"/>
    </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

Has someone ever faced with this problem and found any solution?

The problem should be fixed on server and not on user environment.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post related codes here (edit your question) ?

Comment: Done. You can also see other examples on http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/actionparam.jsf?c=actionparam&tab=usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichFaces 3.x does not support IE9. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326359/854386) for more details.

Possible solutions (as stated in the referenced answer):

1. Upgrade to RichFaces 4.
2. Turn on or force IE8 compatibility mode
3. Patch RichFaces 3 (mostly javascripts) to make it work with IE9 in native mode (refer to the JBoss forum topic from the referenced answer for more details).

Comment: Andrey can you add note "without compatibility mode"? With this note your answer make sense. Without it answer is not correct. See my answer.

Comment: @VasilLukach Well, the referenced answer says about this workaround, I summarized the possible solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE 9+ with IE8 compatibility mode. Add meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` and try it.