# a4j reRender not working(requires refresh (Ie11))

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, richfaces, internet-explorer-11, rerender

I'm using JSF 1.2 on IE11. Recently I added Richfaces api - 3.3.3, Richfaces impl- 3.3.3, Richfaces ui - 3.3.3 , in order to solve the issues I've been getting while migrating from IE 8 to IE 11. After these jars were added, I've been getting issues with the reRender.

Scenario is, a selectonemenu change event triggers is supposed to render another a4j outputPanel panel. But this only happens after a refresh(pressing F5).

Without these jars, my project seems to be working fine, except the IE 11 compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

RichFaces 3 does not support IE9 (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978407/ie9-richfaces-rendering-problem/7326359#7326359) for more details). And likely does not support IE10+.

You can test it out on [demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/inplaceSelect.jsf?c=inplaceSelect&tab=usage) environment. If it does not work your options are to upgrade JSF/RF or add IE compatibility headers.