# Trouble with Richfaces and IE 10 & 11

Tags: internet-explorer, richfaces, compatibility

We are currently using an older version of Richfaces (version 3.3) which has issues with IE 10 and 11, namely with loading modal panels. The work around that I have is manually changing the setting for the document mode in IE to 'Standards'. However if I try to do this via the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` or the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` tag , it does not work.
Is there a different way to do this? Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for meta should be `IE=EmulateIE8` and it should appear close to the top of the document.
More reliable way of doing it is to set Response Header. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7326359/854386

Comment: Tried setting the response with `IE=Edge` and it seems to do the trick. Will test some more now. Thanks